# Ubuntu 13.10, not recognizing 2nd monitor

Tags: nvidia, monitor, signal

Just installed ubuntu for the first time and my monitor isn't showing up on the display settings.  I am on a laptop with nivdia graphics if that helps.  I believe I have bumblebee installed. Other videos show that you should go into your nivdia software and change it...but i don't believe I have it...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open Ubuntu Software Center > Top Menu Bar > Edit > Software Sources > Additional Drivers

It should search for available drivers (Make sure you have an internet connection)

Select the latest Nvidia driver (I always select the latest one that says "tested" in the description)

Click Apply Changes.

#### -0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0

Click the checkmark next to my answer if it helps you!

Comment: I tried it and it said no additional drivers...?

Comment: Then you probably don't have an ext nvidia graphics card. It's probably an Integrated Chip on the motherboard. 

Make and model of the laptop?

Comment: I found the solution...currently bumblebee doesn't support my laptop with HDMI out.  But, apparently the mini DisplayPort works. I'll go buy an adapter and check it out.